# Use python 3 regex to match a string in double quotes

Tags: python, regex

I want to match a string contained in a pair of either single or double quotes. I wrote a regex pattern as so:

```
pattern = r"([\"\'])[^\1]*\1"
mytext = '"bbb"ccc"ddd'
re.match(pattern, mytext).group()
```

The expected output would be:

```
"bbb"
```

However, this is the output:

```
"bbb"ccc"
```

Can someone explain what's wrong with the pattern above? I googled and found the correct pattern to be:

```
pattern = r"([\"\'])[^\1]*?\1"
```

However,  I don't understand why I must use `?`.

Comment: Where's the `?` mark?

Comment: `'?'` matches non-greedily (the shortest possible match)

Comment: It is not a correct expression that you found. Inside a character class, backreferences cannot be used.

Comment: ***" I don't understand why I must use `?`"*** :  you may want to read http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your regex

```
([\"'])[^\1]*\1
```

***Character class*** is meant for matching only one character. So your use of `[^\1]` is incorrect. Think, what would have have happened if there were more than one characters in the first capturing group.

You can use negative lookahead like this

```
(["'])((?!\1).)*\1
```

**or** simply with alternation

```
(["'])(?:[^"'\\]+|\\.)*\1
```

**or**

```
(?<!\\)(["'])(?:[^"'\\]+|\\.)*\1
```

if you want to make sure `"b\"ccc"` does not matches in string `bb\"b\"ccc"`

Comment: \1 inside the character class is not a back reference, try it. Also, a tempered greedy token is rather "heavy" for this task. I'd use alternation here.

Comment: @wiktor i know its not backreference inside character class..i was just trying to contradict if it were..agree with second part

Answer (score 2):

You should use a negative lookahead assertion. And I assume there won't be any escaped quotes in your input string.

```
>>> pattern = r"([\"'])(?:(?!\1).)*\1"
>>> mytext = '"bbb"ccc"ddd'
>>> re.search(pattern, mytext).group()
'"bbb"'
```

Comment: I don't think you need lookahead assertions because there will be only 1 match (`"bbb"`).  `"ccc"` won't match because the first `"` belongs to `"bbb"`, am I wrong?

Comment: ya , it should match `"bbb"` only not `"ccc"`

Comment: so, why are you using lookahead assertions on it ? I'm not following you.

Comment: Why you think like this `I don't think you need lookahead assertions because there will be only 1 match ("bbb")` ? take the first `(["'])` and last `\1`. So there must be starting and end quotes. How end quote matched by one pattern would got matched another time?

Comment: Because there is only 1 match on the OP string

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
pattern = r"[\"'][^\"']*[\"']"
```

https://regex101.com/r/dO0cA8/1

---

`[^\"']*` will match everything that isn't `"` or `'`

Comment: Thank you for your feedback but, according to the OP example, `"b'bb"ccc` doesn't exist.