# trying to find patterns within double quotes in python using regex

Tags: python, regex

Suppose I have a string

```
str='hello this is "vijay_kapoor" and welcome '
```

Now I want to filter only the words which are in double quotes `" "` so the output is `vijay` 
what would be the regular expression for that?

I have tried:

```
re.search('"[a-zA-Z0-9_]*"', str').group()
```

but it didn't work.

Comment: *"didn't work"* - please give a [mcve], currently it's not syntactically valid. You need to escape the quotes, and that character class already exists; use `r'\"\w+\"'` The output will be `'vijay_kapoor'`, though, not just `'vijay'`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use python 3 regex to match a string in double quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37613908/use-python-3-regex-to-match-a-string-in-double-quotes)

Comment: @vijay kumar, has the answer posted below helped? If it did you may accept it by clicking on the tick sign beside it. cheers

Answer (score 1):

`\"(.+?)\"` should work fine:

```
import re
def double_quotes(text):
  matches=re.findall(r'\"(.+?)\"',text)
  return ", ".join(matches)

print(double_quotes('hello this is "vijay_kapoor" and welcome'))
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
vijay_kapoor
```

**EDIT**:

if the intention is to further get the name before `_` You may split it:

```
print(double_quotes('hello this is "vijay_kapoor" and welcome, ').split('_', 1)[0])
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
vijay
```

Comment: the desired output is `vijay` only

Answer (score 1):

Don't be frustrated as a beginner. The code should work here.

```
import re
string='hello this is "vijay_kapoor" and welcome '
regex = re.compile(r'\x22(\w+)_')
match = regex.search(string)
print(match.group(1))
```

### Python [demo](https://onlinegdb.com/SywnfLrLN)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
re.search('"[a-z]+_',str).group()[1:-1]
```